# set curserAt of Jquery Dragable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css

I am dragging an image that is Jquery Dragable. when i drag it from bottom left it move my cursor at center of the image and image change its position before start dragging.I searched about it and find that cursorAt is for this but it still not working what about if i start dragging from top right.How can i make smooth dragging from where ever we start dragging

for better understanding this is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/axtruo/5Vxsz/)

```
    $("#dragable").draggable()
    .css({"transform":" scale(0.79)"
         ,"opacity":"0.90"
         ,"left":"140px"
          ,"top":"35px"
          ,"transform":"Scale(2.50)"});
});    
     // How can i set cursorAt with current poistion of dragging
```